# Number of unique combinations using zeros and ones

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

What is the number of unique combinations of size 10, formed by using only 00 and 111?

0000000000, 1110011100, 0011100000, 0000011100, 1110000000, 0000111111, 1111110000... etc

My approach is, the number of unique combinations of size 10, using only 0s and 1s is 2^10 and remove all combinations other than 00 and 111 $$\frac{2^{10}}{(2^{2}-1) (2^{3}-1)}$$

Is this the right answer ?

Comment: The expression you've given can't be the number of anything, because it is not an integer.

Comment: What is the number of such expressions that can be formed?

Comment: There are only two mutually exclusive cases.  Either there are $(0)$ occurrences of $111$, or there are $(2)$ occurrences of $111$.

Comment: Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).
As onerous as the article may appear to you, it provides a defense mechanism against the MathSE forum being used as a *do my homework* forum.  In particular, please see the **Edit-Tools** section of the article, and the portion of the article that discusses *showing work*.  Homework problems are allowed, as long as the protocol is
observed.

Comment: You consider 0011100000, 0000011100, 1110000000 valid combinations, but they each have an odd number of zeroes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:$A=111$ and $B=00$,

-you can made your sequence using $B$ alone.
so you will have $BBBBB$

-or you can  use $A$ and $B$ together,in this case you have to use each of them twice.

there is no other possibility.

Comment: That's a good hint!  Clear and helpful but doesn't give away too much.

Comment: Grammar tip:  You're is a contraction for you are.  You meant to use the word your, meaning belonging to you.

Comment: @MJD i think with this clarification  he must to be able to applies the basic that he learned in combinatoric ,i just want to Show him how to see the problem more clearly

Comment: @MJD do you think i have to publish it as a comment not as answer?

Comment: I think it's very good the way it is. Welcome to Math.SE.